# images does not display when hover thumbs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I ve got a problem with my function in jquery.
Its a simple hover event lightbox.
Does not trough errors in console, its ok, but cant get my large image appears when hover the thumbnail.

```
CSS

.lightbox a img {
    border: 0;
    display: block;
}
.lightbox a {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
}
#largeImage {
    position: absolute;
    padding: .5em;
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    border: 1px solid #bfbfbf;
}
```

tested in webkit.

This is my function.

```
<div class="lightbox">
    <a href="images/img4-lg.jpg" title=""><img src="images/img4-thumb.jpg" alt="Image"></a>
    <a href="images/img5-lg.jpg" title=""><img src="images/img5-thumb.jpg" alt="Image"></a>
</div>

    /*
    * Lightbox
    */ 

    var offsetY = 10;
    var offsetX = 20;

     $('.lightbox a').hover(function(event) {

        /* Stuff to do when the mouse enters the element */
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        $('<img id="largeImage" href="'+ href +'"/>')
        .css('top', event.pageY + offsetY)
        .css('left', event.pageX + offsetX)
        .appendTo('body');

     }, function() {

        /* Stuff to do when the mouse leaves the element */
        $('#largeImage').remove();

     });

     $('.lightbox a').mousemove(function(event) {

        /* Act on the event */
        $('#largeImage')
        .css('top', event.pageY + offsetY)
        .css('left', event.pageX + offsetX);
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in this...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     //Your Code  
});
```

**Alternatively,** have you remembered to import the jQuery library?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```